# ADO.NET Entity Data Model serialization issues

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ado.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am very new to this framework. I let VS scaffold a data model off of my existing database, and I am having issues trying to GET the data correctly from its API 2 controller.

Here is the model:

```
namespace AngularWebApi.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    public partial class BlockDeveloper
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage",        "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public BlockDeveloper()
        {
            this.Reviews = new HashSet<Review>();
            this.Topics = new HashSet<Topic>();
        }

        public int DeveloperId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PassWord { get; set; }
        public string eMail { get; set; }
        int PostCount { get; set; }
        public int RespondCount { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the GET I am trying to perform:

```
namespace AngularWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class BlockDevelopersController : ApiController
    {
         private AngularSiteEntities4 db = new AngularSiteEntities4();

        // GET: api/BlockDevelopers
        public IQueryable<BlockDeveloper> GetBlockDevelopers()
        {
            return db.BlockDevelopers;
        }

        //....more actions...
    }
}
```

I kept getting the following error:

> Type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.BlockDeveloper_2BE89EC23AFBD5F46CBA6ED3403E8895016357CD4A3553D07BA526B43E774273' with data contract name 'BlockDeveloper_2BE89EC23AFBD5F46CBA6ED3403E8895016357CD4A3553D07BA526B43E774273:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

I have read quite a few posts and forums and two key solutions pop up: the use of [KnownType(typeof(T))], and Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;.

I have thrown the KnownType attributes all over the place in my code with no luck - I have absolutely no idea where to do this in an automatically generated ADO.NET entity data model.

I did finally try "Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;" in my BlockDevelopersController and I no longer get the error. I can finally see my list of BlockDeveloper's - but with one issue, none of the child objects (Reviews, Topics) are being presented (they are empty tags when serialized). I know the data exists, because if I debug and individually loop through each BlockDeveloper's Reviews and Topics I can see it.

I am quite lost as to how to get all of my data. Is there a way to get it if I am using "Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;"? I seem to be reading that I cannot. How can I use the "[KnownType(typeof(T))]" attribute to correct this (where EXACTLY do these attributes go in an ADO.NET entity data model project?).

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: I think the serialization fails because of the virtual properties in your model. When the model gets serialized to JSON, it tries to serialize the collections of reviews & topics too, which probably have references to BlockDeveloper (maybe more?). You have to make sure the serialization doesn't get stuck in an endless loop

Comment: I normally turn my Entities into POCO classes and send these via Web Api.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck - you were correct, the entity models did have references to BlockDeveloper (and more) which (if I understood you correctly) would definitely cause a looping issue during serialization. I am not sure why they were automatically setup this way if it could cause an issue like this. I removed the references so that each entity model would have a one-way relationship to its dependencies. Still getting the issue.... Removing tag "virtual" removes the errors, but does not populate the child entities at all. I will keep looking at it, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If the `Review` and `Topic` entities no longer have a reference to `BlockDeveloper`, you should use .Include("Review") in your database call. That should load the child entities of blockdeveloper

Comment: @AlexanderDerck - Great advise, this allows me to fully return my BlockDeveloper entity through the API! So, I had to remove the unwanted references created when my AngularSite model was created (still not sure why they were created in the first place if it is wrong), I had to add "Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;" to my context, and I had to finally add ".Include("Reviews").Include("Topics")" to my call to the db. Thanks much! I will give you some time to respond with the answer in case you want to, otherwise I will make it the answer so others might find it easily, thanks again.

Comment: Glad you've been able to solve it! Had my own bit of problems with serialization a while back. I still need to look into JSON.NET library, apparantly it has some options to deal with circular references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtual properties in your model cause an infinite loop when you try to serialize them to JSON, since `Review` and `Topic` have references to `BlockDeveloper` and vice versa. You should use eager loading to get the `Review` and `Topic` models from your database with include, instead of trying to lazy-load them.

Comment: Upvoted, once my rep goes to 15 it will count, thanks!

Comment: Accepting the answer gives +2

Comment: Could have sworn I did, sorry.